# Can we change the theme in Messages in iOS 10?

Tags: ios, ios10

I saw that Apple made SDKs for Messages and I am just wondering if there is a chance that we can change the themes and styles of the app. I am tired of the boring look of Messages and have noticed all the cool things people have done with Lydia on their Jailbroken iPhones. Is it going to finally be possible to make some changes to the look and feel of Messages or is it only going to be sticker related?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: If you are bored with iOS, buy an Android. That's your only simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update of Message app in iOS 10 is limited to stickers and extensions, and probably the only alternative theme for the app (without jailbreak) is the dark theme that Apple will introduce in the next version of iOS.